# Problema al pulsar sobre elemento de una coleccion

Tags: javascript, css, html5, materialize

Me encuentro con un problema a la hora de pulsar sobre un elemento de una coleccion. Adjunto el código y os comento.

```
mostrarListaEjercicios:function(datos){
  $('#listaEjercicios').remove();
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('alu')){
    var cadena = '<div id="listaEjercicios"><ul class="collection">';
    cadena = cadena + '<li class="collection-header"><h4>Lista de Ejercicios</h4></li>'

    for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){

      cadena = cadena + '<li class="collection-item avatar"><a href="#!" ><i class="material-icons circle">create</i>';
      cadena = cadena + '<span class="title">'+datos[i].nombre+'</span><p>'+datos[i].dificultad+'</p>';
      cadena = cadena + '<a class="secondary-content"><i class="medium material-icons" >play_circle_outline</i></a></a></li>'
    }
    cadena=cadena+'</ul>';
    cadena=cadena+'</div>';
    $('#messageDiv').append(cadena);

     $('.collection li a span').click(function(){
      var nombreEjercicio=$(this).text();
      if (nombreEjercicio!=""){
        var textoEjercicioElegido;
        var respuestaEjercicioElegido;
        for(var j=0;j<datos.length;j++){
          if(datos[j].nombre==nombreEjercicio){
            textoEjercicioElegido=datos[j].texto;
            respuestaEjercicioElegido=datos[j].respuesta;
          }
        }
        rest.elegirEjercicio(nombreEjercicio);
        app.mostrarEjercicio(textoEjercicioElegido);
      }
    })
  }
},
```

El problema es el siguiente. Al pulsar sobre la colección, para que me haga las acciones de dentro del `$('.collection li a span').click(function())`, debo de pulsar sobre la etiqueta , ya que necesito capturar el valor que tengo en ella. Lo que me gustaría conseguir, es que al pulsar sobre cualquier parte de dicho elemento de la colección, y no en concreto sobre la etiqueta , me realizara las mismas acciones. El problema que me encuentro, es que si hago `$('.collection li a').click(function())` no se captura el valor de la etiqueta  con `var nombreEjercicio=$(this).text();`

Comment: Podrías poner el click sobre el `<li>` padre y luego hacer `$(this).find('span').text()` (busca dentro del `<li>` el hijo que sea un `<span>`)

Comment: Exacto, eso es, muchas gracias por la ayuda